# Import Error of Kmeans in python3.5

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
In [1]: import sqlite3

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [5]: from sklearn.cluster import Kmeans
```

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-0125bea01c25> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.cluster import Kmeans

ImportError: cannot import name 'Kmeans'
```

Scikit-learn version is 0.18.2

Comment: `from sklearn.cluster import KMeans`

Comment: What is your system ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a typo. The "m" in KMeans should be capital:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
```

Comment: That did it,i am just plain ashamed, i did multiple re-installation and other stuff but didn't think of this,thanks man.